# Realm query where member array contains string

Tags: android, realm

I am wondering how to make a query to find all `MyRealmClass` objects where `myDbStrings` contains a `String`.

`MyRealmClass` class is:

```
public class MyRealmClass extends RealmObject {

private RealmList<DbString> myDbStrings;
```

`DbString` class is:

```
public class DbString extends RealmObject {

    private String string;

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

Since it's wrapper class for `String`, is it even possible to construct such a query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can search the fields of objects even if they are part of a RealmList, so the following should work:

```
realm.where(MyRealmClass.class).equalTo("myDbStrings.string", "mySearchTerm").findAll()
```

I just realised this is not part of our documentation, which is something we should definitely fix.

Comment: It's actually in the documentation right here https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries

Comment: Ups, apparently I cannot even search our own documentation :). That section is purely about single object references though. We should probably expand it to Lists as well.